# iceface 2.0: How to retain value in icepush?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I would like to integrate ice push into my web application.

I have a page(placeinfo.jsf) shows information of a place and ui:include weather.jsf for weather information of the place.

Users access to the page at http://xxx.com/xxx/placeinfo.jsf?place=california.

Simple example of code, 
**placeinfo.jsf 

1) ice:output value="placeInfoBean.population"

2) ice:output value="placeInfoBean.language"

3) ui:include src="./weather.xhtml"**

**weather.jsf 

1) ice:output value="weatherBean.humidity"

2) ice:output value="weatherBean.visibility"**

**PlaceInfoBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="placeInfoBean")
@RequestScoped
public class PlaceInfoBean
{
    String population;
    String language;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
       HttpServletRequest request= (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
       String place = request.getParameter("place");
       setPopulation(PlaceInfoDao.getPopulation(place));
       setLanguage(PlaceInfoDao.getlanguage(place));
    }
}
```

**WeatherBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="weatherBean")
@RequestScoped
public class WeatherBean
{
    String humidity;
    String visibility;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
       HttpServletRequest request= (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
       String place = request.getParameter("place");
       setHumidity(WeatherDao.getHumidity(place));
       setVisibility(WeatherDao.getVisibility(place));
    }

    public WeatherBean()
    {
        PushRenderer.addCurrentSession("weather");
    }
}
```

I have another page to update the weather, and the method calls 
   **PushRenderer.render("weather");**
   WeatherBean actually did a refresh, postconstrust method run again, but found there is no request param of "place" which suppose to be "california", and the page doesn't work properly then.

Question: 
1) May I know besides session, how can the page remembers the value before PushRenderer did something?

2) Is it a proper way to get the request param for WeatherBean?
   or request param should be passed by ui:param from placeInfo.jsf?
   How to get the value of ui:param in WeatherBean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the managed beans as @SessionScoped? Or @ApplicationScoped? Did it work?